# What is the best way to generate a PDF and Excel file from ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to generate a PDF and an Excel file from my ASP.net MVC application.
Any ideas on the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a PDFActionResult and an ExcelActionResult

EDIT

Example for an excelactionresult: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to create the PDF and return it with a [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend writing a reporting services report (RDLC), deploying it with the web application, and using the [report viewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) to render the output.
Bringing reporting services in may seem like a steep learning curve, but it is not too bad. You get the added benefit of a solid solution that supports other formats. You don't need a report server for this deployment scenario - not even SQL Server.

Comment: This was our solution for generating reports as both excel and word format, though as a file result rather than with the report viewer. One caveat though, if the reports fail on your server, you'll probably need to deploy the Microsoft.ReportViewer .dll's to your bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

something like abcpdf is cool for creating the PDF, as for excel you just need to create a datatable from your dataset

```
       var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
        grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        grid.DataSource = yourdatahere;
        grid.DataMember = yourdatahere.Stats.TableName;

        grid.DataBind();

        // render the DataGrid control to a file

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.xls"))
        {
            using (var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                grid.RenderControl(hw);
            }
        }
```

as for doing it with a pdf, that would depend on what route you take!

Answer (score 0):

For PDF, you can use [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/). For Excel, I think [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/) will be good (although I've never used it, I have used their Word component and it rocks).

Answer (score 0):

- PDF - use [NFOP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nfop/), [PdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/)  or [iSharpText](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)
- Excel - if you need plain data as a spreedshet, then render as plain-text CSV file. If you need formatting and all the whistles, then use [GBSpreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/GBSpreadsheet.htm).